# How to create multicell table FPDF

Tags: php, fpdf

I wrote following code to create a table with multicell

```
$this->Cell(25, 25, "SR.No.", 'LTRB', 0, 'L', true);
    $this->Cell(60, 25, "CHALLAN", 'LTRB', 0, 'L', true);
    $this->Cell(300, 25, "JOB NAME", 'LTRB', 0, 'L', true);
    $this->Cell(60, 25, "QTY.", 'LTRB', 0, 'L', true);
    $this->Cell(60, 25, "RATE", 'LTRB', 0, 'L', true);
    $this->Cell(90, 25, "AMOUNT", 'LTRB', 1, 'C', true);
    $i=1;
    while($row  =   mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
    $x = $this->x;
    $y = $this->y;
    $push_right = 0;
    $this->MultiCell($w = 25,25,$i,1,'C',0);
    $push_right += $w;
    $this->SetXY($x + $push_right, $y);
    $this->MultiCell($w = 60,25,$row[3],1,'C',0);
    $push_right += $w;
    $this->SetXY($x + $push_right, $y);
    $this->MultiCell($w = 300,25,$row[2],1,'L',0);
    $push_right += $w;
    $this->SetXY($x + $push_right, $y);
    $this->MultiCell($w = 60,25,$row[4],1,'L',0);
    $push_right += $w;
    $this->SetXY($x + $push_right, $y);
    $this->MultiCell($w = 60,25,$row[5],1,'L',0);
    $push_right += $w;
    $this->SetXY($x + $push_right, $y);
    $this->MultiCell($w=90,25,$row[6],1,'C',1);
    $this->Ln();
    $i++;
    }
```

My code generating this output
[image]

Bu that is not align i want to remove space from both row and equal height of each column tried many time but didnt resolved.

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/69624966/2408879

Answer (score 1):

You have used Multicell. Multicell's height is according to line, not box.And Cell's height is according to box. Hence, text came up in 2 lines and height become 50px (25*2) and remaining cell is of height 25px. Use cell of height 50px (in your case) instead of multicell if content is static or use multicell if the content is dynamic and calculate height accordingly. For ex:- your box height become 50px. So for remaining multicell, set height to 50px.

Comment: how to calculate height if the content is dynamic?

Comment: you have to calculate character count in specified width and then find the number of lines and then calculate height. like if it is taking 2 lines and height is 25px and then height is 50px.