# Trying to set up a table with MultiCell in FPDF

Tags: php, fpdf

In PHP I'm trying to set up a 'table' but can't seem to set my cell height uniformly along a row:
[image]

And I've added a line break so you can see the issue more clearly:
[image]

I would like to get a clean table format where the row where "This is my long..." is all the same cell height. But the only function on the documents was `GetStringWidth()` so I don't see how I can apply that to the case here.

This is the desired output:

[image]

This is my code:

```
//Custom hard coded widths for the template
$width = array(12, 20, 30, 20, 15, 12, 20, 18, 25, 15, 10);
foreach ($row as $col) {
    $y = $this->GetY();
    $x = $this->GetX();
    $this->MultiCell($width[$i], 3, $col, 1, 'C', FALSE);
    $this->SetXY($x + $width[$i], $y);
    $i++;
}
```

---

---

EDIT: 
After doing some more research I found that this library won't give me what I need, it actually lacks majority of the things a basic library has so I've decided to use `tcpdf` as my library.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

For such result, use this script: http://www.fpdf.org/en/script/script3.php